# Loading CSS dynamically into the active document using a firefox extension and jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I came upon this [article on using jQuery in Firefox add ins](http://gluei.com/blog/view/using-jquery-inside-your-firefox-extension).  I have it working just fine but am having a CSS issue. How in the world do you get a CSS file into the current browser document?  I've done the obvious:

```
$mb = jQuery.noConflict(); 
doc = window.content.document;
jQuery('body', doc)
    .append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://ThriftyHippo/content/styles.css" />');
```

and that adds the node you think it would to the document's dom.  I've also verified that the chrome:// link included resolves to the right CSS file. However, when I add a div to the document after with an ID defined in the stylesheet it doesn't get styled!  Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the `link` tag has to be added to the `head` of the document, not the `body`. Try that first.

```
jQuery(document.createElement("link"))
 .attr({type: "text/css",href: "chrome://ThriftyHippo/content/styles.css",rel:"stylesheet"})
 .appendTo("head");
```

Comment: After trying this, firebug is showing that the link has been added to the top of the page, but html tags that are referenced in the CSS are not effected. Firebug is also not registering the style modifications.